# Remove white bars on certain browser format - video background

Tags: html, css, video, background, overflow

I have a background-video, and if I scale the browser to a certain with & height it shows white bars, is there any way to fix this?

html:

```
<video src="background/background1.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background"> </video>
```

css:

```
html{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;    

}

#background{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 640px;
    min-height: 360px;
}
```

Solution I've looked at:

```
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width : 100%;
  max-width : 100%;
  height : 0;
  padding : 56.25% 0 0 0; /* 100%/16*9 = 56.25% = Aspect ratio 16:9 */
  overflow : hidden;
}

.video-wrapper > * {
  position : absolute;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  top : -11%;
  left : 0;
  border: none;

}
```

the solution above does the exact same as the code I have now.. can I force a browser to always have a 16:9 format, or make it so that it overflows just before the whitebar shows, on different resolutions?

Answer (score -1):

Try use jquery window resize function http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  ...
});
```